# How to get next or previous attribute id in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, attributes, jquery-attributes

I have the following code

```
<a class="getty" id="1" href="/...">One<./a>
<a class="getty" id="2" href="/...">Two<./a> 
<a class="getty" id="3" href="/...">Three<./a>
```

When I'll click on Left or right, I'll need to get the previous ID.
Example : If I'm on `id="2"`, I need to get `id="1"` if I click on left.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
       $('.getty').attr("id");
       return false;
    } });
    if (e.keyCode == 33) {
       $('.getty').attr("id");
       return false;
    } 
});
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! You do have a question! Sorry, just thought it was funny ;-P

Comment: Seriously, with 32 questions you should really know how to format your posts by now. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help *Edit:* And look at what we've done, guys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the previous id when link is clicked.

```
$('.getty').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $(this).prev().attr('id');
    alert(x);

});
```

You can do the same for next by using the `next()` function

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/H3hdy/

Comment: Now, I'm doing : alert($('.getty').next().attr("id");) And it displays null

Comment: Use the alert in the click event and make use of $(this) to target current clicked item e.g. alert($(this).next().attr("id"));

Comment: @steffi as Marc said, in your alert use `$(this)` instead of `$('.getty')`. It's also recommended to set a conditional for the last item since doing next() on the last `<li>` will get you undefined.

Comment: I tried `alert($(this).next().attr("id"));` but it's the same

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) function to get the next sibling, and [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling.

Answer (score 1):

As GregInYEG mentioned, you need the jQuery next function, but since you are using keys binded to the document, you will also need a way to track which one is the current one.

Comment: I don't really understand :S : `a way to track which one`

Comment: In your example, you're on `id='2'` and you can use the `.prev()` to go to `id='1'`. But, in your javascript, you're targeting `$('.getty')` which doesn't specify which one you are targeting to go to the next or previous one. Also, because you're using keystrokes, not a click, you can't just target based on the one a user clicked on.

So, you can either add a class to the id that you're currently on, or store the id of the current one in a variable.

I may have been overthinking what you needed, but hopefully this clears up what I meant.

Comment: Now, I'm doing : `alert($('.getty').next().attr("id");)` And it displays `null`